# Mac OSX Jenkins Sonar with Xamarin issue

Tags: xamarin, jenkins, xamarin.forms, sonarqube

I have been trying to run SonarQube in jenkins for my Xamarin project. I was able to build the project successfully using jenkins.

My SonarScanner is installed like here,

[image: Screen Shot]

I am getting following error, when i tried to run the sonar scanner through my builder.

```
> [app] $ dotnet /Users/zumry/.jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:appid /n:xamarin_app /v:1.0 /d:sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 ******** sonar.login=admin sonar.password=admin

> FATAL: Cannot run program "dotnet" (in directory "/Users/zumry/.jenkins/workspace/app"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dotnet" (in directory "/Users/zumry/.jenkins/workspace/app"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: Make sure dotnet is in your PATH that the jenkins agent uses.